# jQuery datatable - using column index, check if a column in jQuery datatable is visible/present

Tags: jquery, datatable, visible

Since [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334690/how-to-determine-if-a-column-is-visible-or-not-on-a-jquery-datatable) did not get any response, I am reposting this.

I am using jQuery's datatable and I occasionally toggle the visiblity of some of the columns using the below code

```
tableId.fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
```

Having done that, there are some other controls on the UI that I have to toggle the visibility for. So, I need to check (Say on page load) if the column with 0 index is visible/hidden/present - whatever. I am looking for something like $("#tableId").isColumnVisible(columnIndex);

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: If you control the dataTable then you already have your answer. `tableId.fnSetColumnVis(0, false);` means 0 is no longer visible. Why would you command your troops to march, then ask them where there are going?

Comment: Thanks Sinetheta. I am not sure if you got my situation. Let's say I have hidden the table column by doing action X bu then a series of other actions A, B and C leads me to a situation to check if the table column is hidden .. how would I check that.. ?

Comment: And who is coding actions A, B, and C? Still you. I guess I'm suggesting that you revisit how you control the elements on your page. If you're going to hide a field, then either record it somewhere, or trigger a custom event which you could then listen for to whatever you need to know the visibility state for. It's not like  the user is typing `tableId.fnSetColumnVis(0, false);` in their console, you have complete control over when that happens and what else comes with it. Coupling your controls with your view tightly like the answer you like will always lead to pain down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know jquery datatable at all but i guess you can just check if the header has the css' `display` property set to `hide`.
Sample code:

```
if($("#tableId .th-1").css("display")=="none"){
   //do hidden related action
} else {
   //do visible related action
}
```

supposing that the column that you are checking has class th-1.
If you want a more general approach i can suggest this:

```
$("#tableId th").each(function(index, element){

    if($(this).css("display")=="none"){
       //do hidden related action
    } else {
       //do visible related action
    }
```

});

This will check for every th of your table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried your first approach and it works but I usually would not like to rely on CSS classes as selector for elements. I would prefer to address this problem using column index (which is referred by a variable again) so as to avoid the risk of CSS name being changed and the solution going for a toss. The second approach may not be good if there are more than 1 columns hidden in a table, right ?

Comment: not really, if there are 2 ore more hidden columns the second approach will still work fine as it search all the columns one by one and apply the if else istructions at each one. So it should be good

Answer (score 1):

Okay no one managed to answer your question really and i too was looking for this trivial task and it took me longer than expected to find out how to do it.

here's how, really easy but not documented properly.

```
 /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object*/
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
```

so essentially, the fnSettings() function also has the aoColumns property available which will hold all column properties set on initialization.

if you have trouble getting the correct index from a visible column you can try using this method (though it doesn't seem to work for header th's only body cells so you'll have to do some computing to figure out the header cell).

```
$('.dataTable td').click( function () {
// Get the position of the current data from the node
var oTable = $(this).closest('.dataTable').dataTable();
var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
console.log(aPos);
} );
```